# Get memory address of current linux process

Tags: c++, linux

How would you get memory address of the current running program in Linux C++?
Also the determine the how much space the process is using up?

Comment: What do you mean by 'memory address of the current running program' exactly?
As for the memory usage, you should able to find that reading `/proc/`

Comment: If you want to find the current location of program break you can use `sbrk`. You can have a look https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk.